# How to add partial dynamic segments in the react router v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've a couple of URLs and I need them to be routed to two different components.

example.com/xyz/2023-03-23 -> Component A

example.com/xyz/2023-03-23T09:00:00Z?timezone=Asia/Calcutta -> Component B

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route
        path={`${path}/:date?`}
        exact
        element={ <ComponentA /> }
      />

      <Route
        path={`${path}/:date'T'*`}
        exact
        element={ <ComponentB /> }
      />
   </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

It seems I cannot achieve the above using react router since the partial dynamic segments are not allowed. https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#splats

If I do conditional rendering it increases the code complexity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Route` path doesn't support partial segment matching, it's all or nothing. See the docs on [Dynamic Segments](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#dynamic-segments).

You are already applying conditional rendering, that's what `react-router` and the routes do, conditionally render content based on the current URL path. The recommendation here is to render a single route on `"/:date?"`, collect the entire dynamic segment in the `date` param and run a REGEX on the `date` path param in the component.

Example:

```
const DateComponent = (props) => {
  const { date } = useParams();

  // apply regular expression on date

  return dateIsA
    ? <ComponentA {...props} />
    : <ComponentB {...props} />;
};
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Routes>
      <Route
        path={`${path}/:date?`}
        element={<DateComponent />}
      />
   </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```